# How to redo git push with a new modified .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

I did `git push` and realised my .gitignore needs a few more entries in it. Now how do I undo my last changes and redo `git push` with the modified .gitignore file?

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot make your changes as a commit on top of what you have already?

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't ever want to do that.

You *could* do it by resetting and then doing the correct commit with force push. But, **don't do that**. I'd only ever do this if I was the only person working on this project.

Just make a new commit and push that.

Comment: I tried a new `add`, `commit` and `push` but it's saying `"nothing to commit, working directory clean"`.